# Check user that can view my files in my server

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

I want to secure my files and not anyone can view my files in express, I want to check who has logged in into my website and then authenticate if he has access to view this file or not , how can I achieve that this is the code I am using to access my files url :

```
app.use("/profile", express.static(__dirname + '/profile'));
```

I want only the user that logged in, he is the only one that can view his profile image and if he is not the user then say for example you are not allowed to view this file.

I am using mongodb as a backend but i don't know if its mongodb authentication or express middleware security ?

Comment: How does the user authenticate to your web server? Login with username and password? Or with an identity provided by someone else (Google, Facebook, etc.)?

Comment: yes with username and password and i save his details into jwt token and store it into cookie inside the browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Discovered how to solve this :

```
const checkImg = async (req, res, next) => {
const token = req.cookies.jwt;
if (token) {
    jwt.verify(
        token,
        process.env.JWTKEY,
        async (err, decodedToken) => {
            if (err) {
                res.json({ status: false });
            } else {
                const user = await UserModal.findById(decodedToken.id);
                const imgUrl = req.originalUrl.split('/')[2];
                const imgUser = user.profileImg;
                if (imgUrl === imgUser || user.admin === "ADMIN") {
                    next();
                }
                else {
                    return res.send("Your are not allowed to view this file")
                }
            }
        }
    );
}else{
return res.send("you are not allowed !")
}
```

}

and here is when i use my middleware :

```
app.use("/images", checkImg , express.static(__dirname + '/images'));
```

this code checks if the user is the same user then he can only see the data and also the admin user can display the data , otherwise send him that he is not allowed to get the data